# How to create a new context per every async operation and use it in a thread-safe manner for storing some data

Tags: c#, asynchronous, caching, thread-safety

I'm working on something like a context-bound caching and a little bit stuck on thread-safety...

Let's say I have the following code:

```
public class AsynLocalContextualCacheAccessor : IContextualCacheAccessor
{
    private static readonly AsyncLocal<CacheScopesManager> _rCacheContextManager = new AsyncLocal<CacheScopesManager>();

    public AsynLocalContextualCacheAccessor()
    {
    }

    public CacheScope Current
    { 
        get
        {
            if (_rCacheContextManager.Value == null)
                _rCacheContextManager.Value = new CacheScopesManager();

            return _rCacheContextManager.Value.Current;
        }
    } 
}

public class CacheScopesManager
{
    private static readonly AsyncLocal<ImmutableStack<CacheScope>> _scopesStack = new AsyncLocal<ImmutableStack<CacheScope>>(OnValueChanged);

    public CacheScopesManager()
    {
        CacheScope contextualCache = _NewScope();

        _scopesStack.Value = ImmutableStack.Create<CacheScope>();
        _scopesStack.Value = _scopesStack.Value.Push(contextualCache);
    }

    public CacheScope Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (_scopesStack.Value.IsEmpty)
                return null;

            CacheScope current = _scopesStack.Value.Peek();
            if (current.IsDisposed)
            {
                _scopesStack.Value = _scopesStack.Value.Pop();
                return Current;
            }

            // Create a new scope if we entered the new physical thread in the same logical thread
            // in order to update async local stack and automatically have a new scope per every logically new operation
            int currentThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            if (currentThreadId != current.AcquiredByThread)
            {
                current = _NewScope();
                _scopesStack.Value = _scopesStack.Value.Push(current);
            }

            return current;
        }
    }

    private static void OnValueChanged(AsyncLocalValueChangedArgs<ImmutableStack<CacheScope>> args)
    {
        // Manual is not interesting to us.
        if (!args.ThreadContextChanged)
            return;

        ImmutableStack<CacheScope> currentStack = args.CurrentValue;
        ImmutableStack<CacheScope> previousStack = args.PreviousValue;

        int threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId; 

        int threadIdCurrent = args.CurrentValue?.Peek().AcquiredByThread ?? -1;
        int threadIdPrevious = args.PreviousValue?.Peek().AcquiredByThread ?? -1;

        // Be sure in disposing of the scope
        // This situation means a comeback of the previous execution context, in case if in the previous scope Current was used.
        if (currentStack != null && previousStack != null
            && currentStack.Count() > previousStack.Count())
            currentStack.Peek().Dispose();
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to satisfy the next test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory(TestCategoryCatalogs.UnitTest)]
    public async Task AsyncLocalCacheManagerAccessor_request_that_processed_by_more_than_by_one_thread_is_threadsafe()
    {
        IContextualCacheAccessor asyncLocalAccessor = new AsynLocalContextualCacheAccessor();
        Task requestAsyncFlow = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            string key1 = "key1";
            string value1 = "value1";

            string key2 = "key2";
            string value2 = "value2";

            CacheScope scope1 = asyncLocalAccessor.Current;

            string initialKey = "k";
            object initialVal = new object();

            scope1.Put(initialKey, initialVal);
            scope1.TryGet(initialKey, out object result1).Should().BeTrue();
            result1.Should().Be(initialVal);

            var parallel1 = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(5);
                var cache = asyncLocalAccessor.Current;
                cache.TryGet(initialKey, out object result2).Should().BeTrue();
                result2.Should().Be(initialVal);

                cache.Put(key1, value1);
                await Task.Delay(10);

                cache.Items.Count.Should().Be(1);
                cache.TryGet(key1, out string result11).Should().BeTrue();
                result11.Should().Be(value1);
            });

            var parallel2 = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(2);
                var cache = asyncLocalAccessor.Current;

                cache.StartScope();

                cache.TryGet(initialKey, out object result3).Should().BeTrue();
                result3.Should().Be(initialVal);

                cache.Put(key2, value2);
                await Task.Delay(15);

                cache.Items.Count.Should().Be(1);
                cache.TryGet(key2, out string result21).Should().BeTrue();
                result21.Should().Be(value2);
            });

            await Task.WhenAll(parallel1, parallel2);

            // Here is an implicit dependency from Synchronization Context, and in most cases
            // the next code will be handled by a new thread, that will cause a creation of a new scope,
            // as well as for any other await inside any async operation,  which is quite bad:( 

            asyncLocalAccessor.Current.Items.Count.Should().Be(1);
            asyncLocalAccessor.Current.TryGet(initialKey, out object result4).Should().BeTrue();
            result4.Should().Be(initialVal);
        });

        await requestAsyncFlow;

        asyncLocalAccessor.Current.Items.Count.Should().Be(0);
    }
```

And actually this test is green, but there is one (or more) problem. So, what I'm trying to achieve, is to create a stack of scopes per every new async operation (if the current scope was accessed) and when this operation is finished I need to successfully come back to the previous stack. I have done this based on a current thread ID (because I didn't find any other way how to do that automatically, but I don't like my solution in any way), but if continuation of async operation was executed not in the initial thread (implicit dependency from current `SynchronizationContext`), but in any other, then this causes the creation of a new scope, which is very bad, as for me.

I would be glad if someone could suggest how to do that correctly, big thanks! :)

UPD 1. Code updated in order to add `static` for every `AsyncLocal` field since the value of every `AsyncLocal` is acquired from `ExecutionContext.GetLocalValue()` which is static, so non-static AsyncLocal just a redundant memory pressure.

UPD 2. Thanks, @weichch for the answer, since comment could be big, I just added additional info directly to the question. So, in my case logic with `AsyncLocal` stuff encapsulated, and what client of my code can do - it only invokes `Current` on `IContextualCacheAccessor`, which will get the instance of an object under `AsyncLocal<CacheScopesManager>`, `AsyncLocal` is used here just to have one instance of `CacheScopesManager` per logical request and share it across this request, similar to IoC-Container scoped lifecycle, but the lifecycle of such object is defined from the creation of the object until the end of the async flow where this object was created. Or let's think about ASP NET Core where we have `IHttpContext`, `IHttpContext` does not seem to be immutable, but is still used as `AsyncLocal` through `IHttpContextAccessor`, isn't it? Similar to this way `CacheScopesManager` was designed.

So, if client code, to get current `CacheScope`, can only invoke `Current` on `IContextualCacheAccessor`, then in case of `AsyncLocal` implementation of `IContextualCacheAccessor` call stack will fall into next code:

```
public CacheScope Current
{
    get
    {
        if (_scopesStack.Value.IsEmpty)
            return null;

        CacheScope current = _scopesStack.Value.Peek();
        if (current.IsDisposed)
        {
            _scopesStack.Value = _scopesStack.Value.Pop();
            return Current;
        }

        // Create a new scope if we entered the new physical thread in the same logical thread
        // in order to update async local stack and automatically have a new scope per every logically new operation
        int currentThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        if (currentThreadId != current.AcquiredByThread)
        {
            current = _NewScope();
            _scopesStack.Value = _scopesStack.Value.Push(current);
        }

        return current;
    }
}
```

and if another thread decided to use `Current`, this will cause the creation of new scope, and since `ImmutableStack<CacheScope>` is 'AsyncLocal', we are saving the stack of the previous async flow from any changes, which means that when we return to it, the stack will be fine without any corruptions (for sure, if hacks were not used). All this was done to make the stack of scopes threadsafe, rather than a real 'AsyncLocal'. So, your code

```
async Task Method1()
{
    Cache.Push(new CacheScope { Value = "Method1" });

    await Task.WhenAll(Method2(), Method3());

    Cache.Pop();
}

async Task Method2()
{
    await Task.Delay(10);

    var scope = Cache.CurrentStack.Peek();
    scope.Value = "Method2";

    Console.WriteLine($"Method2 - {scope.Value}");
}

async Task Method3()
{
    await Task.Delay(10);

    var scope = Cache.CurrentStack.Peek();

    Console.WriteLine($"Method3 - {scope.Value}");
}
```

in case if my accessor is used, will not cause mutation in the async flow which will be reflected in another one (and adding data to the scope of the previous async flow, before thread switching - is fine for me). But there is one problem, actually, the purpose of this `CacheScope` is to have some storage that goes across the logical request and caches some data, and this data is scoped to `CacheScope` and will be popped up from the referencable memory, as soon as the scope will end. And I want to minimize the creation of such scopes, which means that if code was executed sequentially, there should not be any reasons to create a new scope, even if continuation of some async operation has happened on another thread because logically code is still 'sequential' and it's ok to share the same scope per such 'sequential' code. Please, correct me if I wrong somewhere.

But your answer and explanation are really useful and for sure will protect others from making mistakes. Also, it helped me to understand what Stephen meant under:

> If you do go down this route, I recommend writing lots and lots of
>   unit tests.

my English is poor and I thought that 'route' means 'link to the article', now understand that it's is rather 'way' in that context.

UPD 3. Added some code of `CacheScope` for a better picture.

```
public class CacheScope : IDisposableExtended
{
    private ICacheScopesManager _scopeManager;
    private CacheScope _parentScope;

    private Dictionary<string, object> _storage = new Dictionary<string, object>();


    internal CacheScope(Guid id, int boundThreadId, ICacheScopesManager scopeManager, 
        CacheScope parentScope)
    {
        _scopeManager = scopeManager.ThrowIfArgumentIsNull(nameof(scopeManager));

        Id = id;
        AcquiredByThread = boundThreadId;

        _parentScope = parentScope;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; }

    public int AcquiredByThread { get; }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<object> Items => _storage?.Values;

    public bool IsDisposed { get; private set; } = false;

    public bool TryExpire<TItem>(string key, out TItem expiredItem)
    {
        _AssertInstanceIsDisposed();

        key.ThrowIfArgumentIsNull(nameof(key));

        expiredItem = default(TItem);

        try
        {
            expiredItem = (TItem)_storage[key];
        }
        catch (KeyNotFoundException)
        {
            // Even if item is present in parent scope it cannot be expired from inner scope.
            return false;
        }

        _storage.Remove(key);

        return true;
    }


    public TItem GetOrPut<TItem>(string key, Func<string, TItem> putFactory)
    {
        _AssertInstanceIsDisposed();

        key.ThrowIfArgumentIsNull(nameof(key));
        putFactory.ThrowIfArgumentIsNull(nameof(putFactory));

        TItem result;

        try
        {
            result = (TItem)_storage[key];
        }
        catch (KeyNotFoundException)
        {
            if (_parentScope != null && _parentScope.TryGet(key, out result))
                return result;

            result = putFactory(key);

            _storage.Add(key, result);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void Put<TItem>(string key, TItem item)
    {
        _AssertInstanceIsDisposed();

        key.ThrowIfArgumentIsNull(nameof(key));

        _storage[key] = item;

        // We are not even thinking about to change the parent scope here,
        // because parent scope should be considered by current as immutable.
    }

    public bool TryGet<TItem>(string key, out TItem item)
    {
        _AssertInstanceIsDisposed();

        key.ThrowIfArgumentIsNull(nameof(key));

        item = default(TItem);

        try
        {
            item = (TItem)_storage[key];
        }
        catch (KeyNotFoundException)
        {
            return _parentScope != null && _parentScope.TryGet(key, out item);
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (IsDisposed)
            return;

        Dictionary<string, object> localStorage = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _storage, null);
        if (localStorage == null)
        {
            // that should never happen but Dispose in general is expected to be safe to call so... let's obey the rules
            return;
        }

        foreach (var item in localStorage.Values)
            if (item is IDisposable disposable)
                disposable.Dispose();

        _parentScope = null;
        _scopeManager = null;

        IsDisposed = true;
    }

    public CacheScope StartScope() => _scopeManager.CreateScope(this);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *create a stack of scopes per every new async operation*? If you have *methodA* calls *methodB*, and both are async methods, do you mean you want to create two scopes one for each?

Comment: @weichch,  seems yes, just to clarify. I mean if in methodA i have two scopes (2,1 in stack order, just to correctly back to appropriate stack), and we call async methodB and await on it, then stack with scopes (3,2,1) should be created and used only in methodB, then when methodB will be finished I need to back to methods where I will have next scopes (2,1). And this stuff works in this way, but then accessing to current scope through CacheScopesManager.Current triggers the creation of a new scope, in situations where SynchronizationContext is the default, which I want to avoid. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Your code is really fighting the way `AsyncLocal<T>` works. Setting in a getter, trying to manage the scopes manually, having an async local manager for an async local type, and the code using the change handler are all problematic.

I believe all this is really to try to deal with the fact that `CacheScope` isn't immutable. The best way to solve this is to make `CacheScope` a proper immutable object. Then everything else will fall into place more or less naturally.

I find it's often easier to write a separate `static` API for immutable objects which is more "async local-friendly". E.g.:

```
public class ImplicitCache
{
  private static readonly AsyncLocal<ImmutableStack<(string, object)>> _asyncLocal = new AsyncLocal<ImmutableStack<(string, object)>>();

  private static ImmutableStack<(string, object)> CurrentStack
  {
    get => _asyncLocal.Current ?? ImmutableStack.Create<ImmutableDictionary<string, object>>();
    set => _asyncLocal.Current = value.IsEmpty ? null : value;
  }

  // Separate API:

  public static IDisposable Put(string key, object value)
  {
    if (key == null)
      throw new InvalidOperationException();
    CurrentStack = CurrentStack.Push((key, value));
    return new Disposable(() => CurrentStack = CurrentStack.Pop());
  }

  public static bool TryGet(string key, out object value)
  {
    var result = CurrentStack.Reverse().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Item1 == key);
    value = result.Item2;
    return result.Item1 != null;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
public async Task AsyncLocalCacheManagerAccessor_request_that_processed_by_more_than_by_one_thread_is_threadsafe()
{
  Task requestAsyncFlow = Task.Run(async () =>
  {
    string key1 = "key1";
    string value1 = "value1";

    string key2 = "key2";
    string value2 = "value2";

    string initialKey = "k";
    object initialVal = new object();

    using var dispose1 = ImplicitCache.Put(initialKey, initialVal);
    ImplicitCache.TryGet(initialKey, out object result1).Should().BeTrue();
    result1.Should().Be(initialVal);

    var parallel1 = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
      await Task.Delay(5);
      ImplicitCache.TryGet(initialKey, out object result2).Should().BeTrue();
      result2.Should().Be(initialVal);

      using var dispose2 = ImplicitCache.Put(key1, value1);
      await Task.Delay(10);

      ImplicitCache.TryGet(key1, out string result11).Should().BeTrue();
      result11.Should().Be(value1);
    });

    var parallel2 = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
      await Task.Delay(2);

      ImplicitCache.TryGet(initialKey, out object result3).Should().BeTrue();
      result3.Should().Be(initialVal);

      using var disose3 = ImplicitCache.Put(key2, value2);
      await Task.Delay(15);

      ImplicitCache.TryGet(key2, out string result21).Should().BeTrue();
      result21.Should().Be(value2);
    });

    await Task.WhenAll(parallel1, parallel2);

    ImplicitCache.TryGet(initialKey, out object result4).Should().BeTrue();
    result4.Should().Be(initialVal);
  });

  await requestAsyncFlow;

  ImplicitCache.TryGet(initialKey, out _).Should().BeFalse();
}
```

Comment: Hi, big thanks for the answer, and for your contribution to popularizing concurrency and nice articles!

I have an async local manager with an async local stack of scopes, just because I have more than one implementation of this caching mechanism, one is based on IoC-Container scopes, another one is straight forward and not threadsafe, but fast, and the last one is based on async local for scenarios where thread-safety is required and they have the same API and the same type under the hood - non-threadsafe CacheScope, accessor and manger are different, and this seems ok, at least for me.

Comment: I thought about usages of ImmutableDictionary instead of CacheScope, but what I'm afraid, it's performance degradation of the immutable dictionary... if just to think, for thread-safety I don't need to create a new instance of dictionary per every mutation if this dictionary will be used only by one thread simultaneously
and because of that, I created a manager, that just creates a new instance of such dictionary per every situation where another thread (or logically new operation) tries to access the scope and making this implicitly because devs can forget about that...

Comment: But this scope bound cache can store 10-1000 of objects, where the influence of the immutable dictionary will be very sensitive in performance of "Put" and GC pressure per every request

Comment: I'm using AsyncLocal, just because it gives me a chance to back to the previous state of the stack of scopes after every awaitable operation and now the only problem is redundant creation of scope and what probably is needed for me it's something like ID of code that was executed in the method and this ID should be different per every async operation, but should be same in case of continuation, probably it's just an async-await illusion of sequential code, and such id cannot even exist from a logical perspective, but yeah...

Comment: When it comes to `AsyncLocal<T>`, the immutability is not about thread safety at all; [it's about being semantically correct](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html). The immutable types share memory under the hood, so while there *is* a definite memory impact, it's probably not as much as you're thinking.

Comment: but i'm really don't want to make CacheScope immutable, because i don't see (probably because lack of experience) real reasons why i should sacrifise performance (Immutable Dictionary straight forward test by [Ayende](https://ayende.com/blog/164739/immutable-collections-performance)) because of what? What can happen if I store muttable dictionary in immutable stack, which is async local? I just want a new muttable scope per new async operation and that's what this async local immutable stack is doing for me, for sure, if i in correct time will put a new instance of CacheScope.

Comment: Did you read the link I posted about semantic correctness? If you do go down this route, I recommend writing lots and lots of unit tests.

Comment: Yes, i read it probably two year ago, then month ago, then yestarday, and today i read it one more time, btw nice article, big thanks! I'm already written different tests that put into `CacheScope` some data, when one thread, two threads, a lot of awaits, and manual `CacheScope` are used, and seems they worked, but continuation of every async method cause a creation of new scope, at least when `SynchornizationContext` is null, which cause a redundant performance degradation and i'm trying to avoid, but it still will be better than new scope per mutation of `CacheScope`

Comment: I'm all for more unit-tests, but I think problem in my imagination, since i cannot find appropriate input, that will corrupt my code related to `AsyncLocal<ImmutableStack<CacheScope>>`, where `CacheScope` is not immutable, and a push of new scope is caused by accessing to `Current` property of `CacheScopeManager` (which just an API around ImmutableStack) which will create a new scope, if current scope was acquired by another thread in comparing with current...

Answer (score 4):

I think @StephenCleary is not saying mutable `CacheScope` is incorrect, but **semantically** incorrect, meaning using mutable `CacheScope` *may* violate the purpose of `AsyncLocal<T>` being used in *your* cache.

`AsyncLocal<T>` is designed for providing access to ambient data which is local to an async control flow. Using mutable data type in `AsyncLocal<T>` could make such *local* data escape its scope.

For example, consider this

```
static class Cache
{
    private static AsyncLocal<ImmutableStack<CacheScope>> StackValue 
        = new AsyncLocal<ImmutableStack<CacheScope>>();

    public static ImmutableStack<CacheScope> CurrentStack
    {
        get => StackValue.Value;
        set => StackValue.Value = value;
    }

    public static void Push(CacheScope scope)
    {
        CurrentStack = CurrentStack.Push(scope);
    }

    public static CacheScope Peek()
    {
        return CurrentStack.Peek();
    }

    public static void Pop()
    {
        CurrentStack = CurrentStack.Pop();
    }
}
```

Assuming there are two methods:

```
async Task Method1()
{
    // Push scope where Value = Method1
    Cache.Push(new CacheScope { Value = "Method1" });

    // Call method2
    await Method2();

    // Unexpected: value = Method2 
    var value = Cache.CurrentStack.Peek().Value;

    Cache.Pop();
}

async Task Method2()
{
    await Task.Delay(10);

    var scope = Cache.CurrentStack.Peek();
    scope.Value = "Method2";
}
```

`Method2` is a new async flow which has its own logical call context copied from `Method1`. However, because the copy is a shallow copy, the two contexts will share the same `CacheScope` instances in the `ImmutableStack`. Mutations made in `Method2` could be unexpectedly reflected into `Method1`.

And remember, we could also do *fork/join*:

```
async Task Method1()
{
    Cache.Push(new CacheScope { Value = "Method1" });

    await Task.WhenAll(Method2(), Method3());

    Cache.Pop();
}

async Task Method2()
{
    await Task.Delay(10);

    var scope = Cache.CurrentStack.Peek();
    scope.Value = "Method2";

    Console.WriteLine($"Method2 - {scope.Value}");
}

async Task Method3()
{
    await Task.Delay(10);

    var scope = Cache.CurrentStack.Peek();

    Console.WriteLine($"Method3 - {scope.Value}");
}
```

You could see two sets of results:

```
Method3 - Method1
Method2 - Method2
```

and

```
Method3 - Method2
Method2 - Method2
```

The mutation made in `Method2` unexpectedly flows into `Method3`.

This kind of unexpected behavior could be problematic to *your* cache. It would be really hard to locate bugs related to the implicit context when the call stack is fairly big, which is why Stephen suggested:

> If you do go down this route, I recommend writing lots and lots of unit tests.